# Searching through array of elements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a small issue with my Excel formula.

In one column I have random strings and the other one is used to standardize the inputs:

```
Column1
Administrator 
Apples 
Apple juice
Orange
Computer device


Lookup column:
Admin
Apple
Orange 
Computer
```

The preferred output would be:

```
OUTPUT
Admin
Apple
Apple
Orange
Computer
```

---

So, basically I want to use xlookup function to go through all elements from lookup array and return the lookup version of the text. I tried using "*" &[lookup array] & "*". The function spills so that is no more a good solution for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried using search function as well but this one also spills and I'm not sure if I need extra function to reduce the result to one cell or maybe I need completely different function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think an example of input and expected output easy to copy/paste would be helpful

Comment: Hey, Sorry  for that. Thought it would be a bit easier but managed to fix that

Comment: I don't think there is a native function in Excel to do this. Maybe with macros could be done but not tested. Anyways, maybe [Fuzzy Lookup](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/vlookup/excel-fuzzy-lookup) can be useful here (not tested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
=XLOOKUP(
    TRUE;
    ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(LookupColumn); String1));
    LookupColumn;
    "No matches"
)
```

EDIT: Changed references to better match the OP example data

Comment: Yes but you need to define what loookUpArray and stringSample refer to and maybe screenshot the result

Comment: I purposely used the reference given by the OP, although slightly different (array instead of column, which I now changed). The output is the desired output.
Normally I'd agree with you, but given the simplicity of the question and the clear references there I didnt see it necessary.

Comment: I tested the formula and the output looks as I wanted it to be! Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not going to find `Apple` in `Appples` so I'm confused as to why you see the results you needed, when this won't work on the given sample data @KrzysztofRobakowski

Comment: @JvdV I actually assumed that was a typo in the question, and not an example of data variation. However, I still regard the question as to how he can use XLOOKUP and SEARCH without spillage.

Comment: @ThomasLilleng okay, who knows. As long as OP is helped!

Comment: @JvdV I didn't see that until you mentioned it. It was a typo from my side, fixed now!